# How do I maintain the new order of my items after I use drag and drop and refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using this drag and drop library to be able to reorder a list of articles on my page: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd

However, even though I'm able to drag them up and down and re-order them, when I refresh the page they go back to their initial state.

The articles are pulled from Cloud Firestore.

**How can I make them maintain the new order each time I move things around?**

```
class Articles extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection("articles");
    this.unsubscribe = null;
    this.onDragEnd = this.onDragEnd.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      articles: [],
    };
  }

  onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
    const articles = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { title } = doc.data();
      articles.push({
        key: doc.id,
        title,
      });
    });
    this.setState({
      articles,
    });
    this.onDragEnd = this.onDragEnd.bind(this);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);
  };

  onDragEnd(result) {
    if (!result.destination) return;
        
    const items = this.state.articles;
    const [reorderedItem] = items.splice(result.source.index, 1);
    items.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);

    this.setState(items)
  }
```

Then in my return(), I've got something like:

```
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}> ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching data from a remote source. So u need to update that remote source after reordering. You have to do this inside `onDragEnd` function. Currently you are only updating your local state with `this.setState(items)`. That's why you lose your reorder on page refresh.

Comment: I think this makes a bit of sense, sorry I'm new to this! So inside the onDragEnd, I should do the update document just like here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data ???

Comment: You can use `this.ref.update(items)` inside the `onDragEnd()`
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data